# If not target on click, hide

Tags: jquery, click, target

This question has been asked a trilion times, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/V9zg6/). You can toggle the login form by clicking on the link. If you then want to hide it, you can click the link again, or click outside the form itself.

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j("a#login-link").click(function (e) {
    $j("div#custom-login").slideToggle("fast");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$j(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($j("div#custom-login").is(":visible") && !$j("div#custom-login, div#custom-login *").is(e.target)) {
        $j("div#custom-login").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

The problem is that clicking inside the form will still hide the form - unless you click at the border, which is strange. A solution is to add a `*` selector to get all child elements, like so:

```
$j(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($j("div#custom-login").is(":visible") && !$j("div#custom-login, div#custom-login *").is(e.target)) {
        $j("div#custom-login").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

But I cannot imagine it can't be done otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple, just add this code:

```
$j("div#custom-login").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();    
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V9zg6/8/)

Comment: Oh, it is *that* easy, huh? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$j(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($j("div#custom-login").is(":visible") && !$j(e.target).closest("#custom-login").length) {
        $j("div#custom-login").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zujYE/3/)

**Important Note**
It is a bad practise to use selectors like `div#custom-login` if you have an id as the selector use only `#custom-login` as the selector

Comment: It is not inside the login-link!

Answer (score 0):

doesn't this line specify it to slide up when it is visible and when it is the selected target?? :O

```
if ($j("div#custom-login").is(":visible") && !$j("div#custom-login, div#custom-login *").is(e.target)) {
```

Comment: `!$j("div#custom-login, div#custom-login *").is(e.target)` = when it is NOT the target (note the exclamation mark).